# Conceptual thread issue

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm generating hashes (MD5) of numbers from 1 to N in some threads. According to the first letter of the hash, the number that generates it is stored in an array. E.g, the number 1 results in c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b and the number 2 in c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c, so they are stored in a specific array of hashes that starts with "c".

The problem is that I need to generate them sorted from the lower to the higher. It is very expensive to sort them after the sequence is finished, N can be as huge as 2^40. As I'm using threads the sorting never happens naturally. E.g. One thread can generate the hash of the number 12 (c20ad4d76fe97759aa27a0c99bff6710) and store it on "c" array and other then generates the hash of the number 8 (c9f0f895fb98ab9159f51fd0297e236d) and store it after the number 12 in "c" array.

I can't simply verify the last number on the array because as far as the threads are running they can be very far away from each other.

Is there any solution for this thread problem? Any solution that is faster than order the array after all the threads are finished would be great.

I'm implementing this in C.

Thank you!

Comment: I can't follow what you're asking. Do you have an array of 16 things (not sure if they're ints or what). Are you trying to make a hash table based on the MD5 hashes?

Comment: By this point, I have 16 arrays, each one with a lot of integers. The hash of each integer points which array it will be stored, as I explained in my question.

Comment: @CrazyCasta, Yes, kind of hash table based on MD5 hashes

Comment: You can have each thread sort their own results and then merge the results at the end.  The merge should be relatively fast.

Comment: Are you sorting inside each of the 16 bins, or is the dispatch to one of the 16 bins the extent of the sorting?

Comment: @CrazyCasta What? I'm not following you anymore :)

Comment: @VaughnCato, each thread sort one array after finished all the hash generations?

Comment: Inside the 'c' bin, do you want them sorted by hash value or int value, or do you just want a list of all the ints that start with 'c'.

Comment: So you're gonna end up with as many as 2^40 MD5 hashes presented in essentially such a way as to detect collisions by way of sorting the hashes after splitting them into buckets. that about sum it up ?

Comment: This is probably a dumb idea, but... the MD5 hashes for the numbers between 1 and 2^40 are never going to change, so there's no real need to generate them 'on the fly'.  Instead, just generate them once (however long it takes -- if it takes a week or a month, fine) and save the results to a large (16TB?) database.  Then you can efficiently do lookups in the database whenever necessary.

Comment: I assume that's what he's doing and that he's looking for the most efficient way to generate said file.

Comment: @CrazyCasta I think you're right... my thought was that since it's only going to need to be done once, ever, efficiency isn't necessarily that important.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, well, you guys are correct. I'm going to store this and look up latter. Anyway efficiency is not the big deal but it is important. With this question I'm just trying to solve this particular problem.

Comment: @FredericoSchardong Would you mind answering my question "Inside the 'c' bin..."

Comment: @CrazyCasta sorry, by int value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having one array for each prefix (eg. "c"), have one array per thread for each prefix.  Each thread inserts only into its own arrays, so it will always insert the numbers in increasing order and the individual thread arrays will remain sorted.

You can then quickly (`O(N)`) coalesce the arrays at the end of the process, since the individual arrays will all be sorted.  This will also speed up the creation process, since you won't need any locking around the arrays.

Comment: @FredericoSchardong: Even better, you could pre-allocate the input numbers to be hashed among the threads (eg thread 1 hashes numbers 0-1023, thread 2 hashes numbers 1024-2047...) so that you can combine the arrays just by concatenating them.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned pthreads I'm going to assume you're using gcc (this is not necessarily the case but it's probably the case). You can use the `__sync_fetch_and_add` to get the value for the end of the array and add one to it in one atomic operation. It would go something like the following:

```
insertAt = __sync_fetch_and_add(&size[hash], 1);
arrayOfInts[insertAt] = val;
```

The only problem you'll run into is if you need to resize the arrays (not sure if you know the array size beforehand or not). For that you will need a lock (most efficiently one lock per array) that you lock exclusively while reallocating the array and non-exclusively when inserting. Particularly this could be done with the following functions (which assume programmer does not release an unlocked lock):

```
// Flag 2 indicates exclusive lock
void lockExclusive(int* lock)
{
    while(!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(lock, 0, 2));
}

void releaseExclusive(int* lock)
{
    *lock = 0;
}

// Flag 8 indicates locking
// Flag 1 indicates non-exclusive lock
void lockNonExclusive(int* lock, int* nonExclusiveCount)
{
    while((__sync_fetch_and_or(lock, 9) & 6) != 0);
    __sync_add_and_fetch(nonExclusiveCount, 1);
    __sync_and_and_fetch(lock, ~8);
}

// Flag 4 indicates unlocking
void releaseNonExclusive(int* lock, int* nonExclusiveCount)
{
    while((__sync_fetch_and_or(lock, 4) & 8) != 0);
    if(__sync_sub_and_fetch(nonExclusiveCount) == 0);
        __sync_and_and_fetch(lock, ~1);
    __sync_and_and_fetch(lock, 4);
}
```